# how to upgrade ruby version from 2.3.1 to 2.5.1 in ubuntu

Tags: ruby

I've installed Ruby 2.3.1p112 from the default Ubuntu repository.

No I'm trying to install the Ruby version 2.5.1 and here is what I did:

```
$ rvm install "ruby-2.5.1"
```

and then

```
$ rvm use 2.5.1 --default
```

And then it complains:

> Required ruby-2.3.1 is not installed.
>   To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.3.1"'
>
> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
>
> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
>   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
>   Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

I did as recommended, but unsuccessfully, every time I ask `$ ruby -v` it keeps telling me 2.3.1p112, then if I try to reinstall 2.5.1 it tells me that it is already installed.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a problem with rvm, first do this in a shell:

```
  rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

Then be sure that your .bashrc, or .zshrc, depending on what shell you use contains this at the last line

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

and restart your shell, it should work, if not try also addding this line to your .XXprofile file or .xxrc file

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

finally it should work, if not, try to reinstall rvm again as single user